# Implementing Asp.NET core 2.2 Sessionstate or tempdata equivalent at page level

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a report in Asp.NET core 2.2 that currently visits the database for each page of data. My objective is to fetch a large subset of data (or the entire set) from the database and then page it logically when rendering it on screen.

I need my controller to remember what was fetched for the duration of the cshtml page, if I use session state or tempdata (instructed to remember the list), then I face the resultset being retained in memory after the user navigates away.

Is there a construct I can use, perhaps something like an old school destructor?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a construct I can use, perhaps something like an old school destructor?

No, there is not. This supposed desctructor should fire only when user navigates to another page after few consecutive visits to the page you want the destructor to be called on. There's no builtin mechanism that would behave this way.

> I use session state or tempdata (instructed to remember the list), then I face the resultset being retained in memory after the user navigates away

Yes, this is how session works. Depending on how large the resultset is, you can end up with too much data retained in server's memory.

> My objective is to fetch a large subset of data (or the entire set) from the database and then page it logically

Usually, what's the best scenario for such requirement is to use the database's paging feature where a specific page is fetched from the database upon a single request.

This way you don't have to store the large subset in your middleware server's memory. Rather, a single page is retrieved from the database, served to the client and immediately removed when a request is completed.